# Counterpart of this script in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html, when input has been changed, will call a javascript function:

```
<input type="file" id="file-uploaded" onchange="checkinput(this);">
```

And the script will read if the input really contains a file:

```
function checkinput(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        // do something...
```

Then, when I try it in jQuery:

```
$(document).on("change", "#file-uploaded", function(){
    if ($(this).files && $(this).files[0]) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

it does not work. What is the right counterpart of the first script when converting it to jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. 
Change this : `$(this).files` to this: `$(this)[0].files`

Your Jquery code now will look like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#file-uploaded", function(){
    if ($(this)[0].files && $(this)[0].files[0]) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

Comment: Also you could use the jquery selector like this $("#file-uploaded").on("change",function(){}); also I think it's important to note that the above works because the $(this) is a jquery element but when you add the [0] it selects the html element rather then jquery's reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
   $("#file-uploaded").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).files && $(this).files[0]) {
            // do something...
        }
    });
```